# the `this` keyword & binding in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Reading through You Don't Know Javascript : this & Object Prototypes, there is quite a lot of mention `this`  binding.  Correct me if I get this wrong, `this` will bind according to where the function was called aka the call-site.

What exactly is `this` binding to when a function is called? And what does binding mean in this context? I probably missed something along the line while reading however just want to be sure what binding means in this context.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It looks like your question has probably been asked - it's a pretty classic JS question. You might want to look at [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: In the context of JavaScript, a **binding** is simply an entry in an environment (scope). It's an umbrella term for variable, parameter, etc. The text could probably have said "`this` *variable*" instead, but `this` isn't like other variables, so that wouldn't be a correct use of the term. The phrase "`this` binding" is also used in the language specification: https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-resolvethisbinding